# Multiple file upload in playframework

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework

I'm having some problems with getting multiple file upload to work. When I select x files, it goes through successfully, but the first file is being uploaded x times, and the others are not being uploaded at all. Anyone able to point out what I am doing wrong?

Form:

```
#{form @Projects.uploadPictures(project.id), enctype:'multipart/form-data'}   

<p>
    <label>&{'title'}</label>
    <input type="text" name="title"/>
    <strong>(&{'addPicture.chooseTitle'})</strong>
</p>
<p>
    <label>&{'Pictures'}</label>
    <input type="file" multiple name="files" id="files"/>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="&{'publish'}" />
</p>

#{/form}
```

Handling the files:

```
public static void uploadPictures(long id, String title, List<Blob> files) {
    String error = "";        
    if(files != null && !title.trim().equals("")) {
        Project project = Project.findById(id);
        // Save uploaded files
        Picture picture;

        for(int i = 0; i<files.size(); i++) {
            if(files.get(i) != null) {
                System.out.println("i: "+i+"\nFiltype: "+files.get(i).type());
                if(files.get(i).type().equals("image/jpeg") || files.get(i).type().equals("image/png")) {
                    picture = new Picture(project, title+"_bilde_"+(i+1), files.get(i));
                    project.addPicture(picture);
                } else {
                    error += "Fil nummer "+(i+1)+" er av typen "+files.get(i).type()+" og ikke av typen .JPG eller .PNG og ble dermed ikke lagt til. \n";
                }
            } else {
                error = "Ingen filer funnet";
            }
        }
    } else {
        error = "Velg en tittel for bildene";
    }
    if(error.equals("")) {
        flash.success("Picture(s) added");
    } else {
        flash.error(error);
    }
    addPicture(id);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it to work like this if anyone is ever interested:

```
public static void uploadPictures(long id, String title, File fake) {
    List<Upload> files = (List<Upload>) request.args.get("__UPLOADS");
    if(files != null) {
        Project project = Project.findById(id);
        Picture picture;
        Blob image;
        InputStream inStream;
        for(Upload file: files) {
            if(file != null) {
                try {
                    inStream = new java.io.FileInputStream(file.asFile());
                    image = new Blob();
                    image.set(inStream, new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file.asFile()));
                    picture = new Picture(project, file.getFileName(), image);
                    project.addPicture(picture); // stores the picture
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    addPicture(id); //renders the image upload view
}
```

Would be happy to get a working solution with an array of Blob objects instead of having to request.args.get("__UPLOADS") if possible.

Comment: Did you see this :P - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401364/multi-file-upload-with-play/7571000#7571000 ?

Answer (score 2):

So you can use @As to bind  the processing of a param to an specific Play TypeBinder

So with this:

```
public static void chargedMultiUpload(@As(binder = FileArrayBinder.class) Object xxx) throws IOException{ ... }
```

And this html

```
<input type="file" multiple name="files" id="files"/>
```

So, you have to make a cast with something like File[] doo = (File[])xxx;

Comment: You can create your own binder so the controller gets cleaner

Answer (score -1):

Should `<input type="file" multiple name="files" id="files"/>` not be: `<input type="file multiple" name="files" id="files"/>`?

Second of all, where do you actually save your image? I think you should save it in your loop, where you put `project.addPicture(picture);`, but actually it looks like the images are saved to the system in your last line: `addPicture(id);` This kinda explains why it saves the same image (last one or first one (not sure how they are parsed)) multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but <input type="file multiple" name="files" id="files"/> didn't render as multiple file upload. project.addPicture(picture) saves the image and addPicture(id) just renders the view for image upload. Any other ideas?

Comment: Definitely not. [`multiple` is a separate attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html#input.file.attrs.multiple) and not part of the value for `type`.