# uploading an image through form

Tags: forms, file-upload, playframework, image-uploading, playframework-1.x

How should i write my controller class to upload an image through a form?

I have created the form like this

```
#{form @index(), enctype:'multipart/form-data'}
    <br/>
    <h4>Image:</h4> <input type="file" name="image" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Photo" />
#{/form}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is agoo introduction here : http://www.lunatech-research.fr/playframework-file-upload-blob

If you upload multiple photos, there is some known problems. Here is a workaround that works for me : [Multiple file upload in playframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635145/multiple-file-upload-in-playframework)

Answer (score 0):

The `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is required to have Play framework handle all the upload.
On the controller side you just have to write :

```
public static void storeImage(File fileUpload) {
    if (fileUpload == null) {
        //Handle the error case
    }
    //Store the file in a perenial location.
    //For example :
    File storeLocation = new File("/relOrAbsPath"), fileUpload.getName());
    boolean success = fileUpload.renameTo(storeLocation);
    //...
}
```

By default Play stores the files in a temporary place.

You can also use annotations as you would do for other controller params.

Comment: Your example really helped me! I have uploaded the image now,    thanks kheraud

Comment: Hey Kheraud, can you help me to import contacts from my facebook account in my application.

Facebook Connect

1. what does fbconnect.id=YOUR_APP_ID_HERE mean and where can i get this value?

2. what does fbconnect.apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE mean and where can i get this value?

3. what does fbconnect.secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET_HERE mean and where can i get this value?

4. what does fbconnect.model=models.User mean and where can i get this value?

5. what does  fbconnect.landUrl=/ mean and where can i get this value?


thanks,
I am looking forward for your help