# Multiple upload file with PlayFramework

Tags: file-upload, playframework

I'm trying to upload multiple files at once with Play Framework, but I always get the first image for each uploaded. Here's a concrete case :

The HTML :

```
<form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="file" name="image" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send images" />
</form>
```

The controller :

```
public static void upload() {
    File[] images = params.get("image", File[].class);
    for (File f : images) {
        Logger.info (f.getName());
    }
}
```

If I upload image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg & image4.jpg, the `Logger.info` on the console will display :

```
image1.jpg
image1.jpg
image1.jpg
image1.jpg
```

The other images won't be used.

I tried with `List<File>` instead of `File[]` but it doesn't work neither.

I also saw there is kind the same question here on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635145/multiple-file-upload-in-playframework)), that use this as an answer :

```
List<Upload> files = (List<Upload>) request.args.get("__UPLOADS");
```

But it doesn't work in the v1.2.4 of Play!.

I'm using Play v1.2.4.

Thank you really much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have opened a [ticket](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1391-multiple-file-uploads-only-show-the-first-file#ticket-1391-1) at Play! Framework because it seems to be problem, and apparently, I'm not the only one to have this behavior.

I tested with the new 1.2.5, and the problem is fixed, at least with the solution I gave on the question :

```
public static void upload() {
    File[] images = params.get("image", File[].class);
    for (File f : images) {
        Logger.info (f.getName());
    }
}
```

Note: I'm using Java 7!

Comment: I didn't tried with 1.2.5, I directly switched to 2.x. If someone puts an update here, I'll be glad to give him/her the accepted answer. If I have the time, I'll try to test with the 1.2.5 branch and update my answer.

Comment: If you're using java 6, could you tell me if it's still don't work or if it's fixed ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the automatic binding instead of looking in the params:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static void index() {
        render();
    }

    public static void upload(File[] files)
    {
        for (File file : files)
        {
            Logger.info(file.getName());
        }

        index();
    }
}
```

The view template:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Home' /}

#{form @upload(), enctype:'multipart/form-data'}
    <input type="file" name="files" />
    <input type="file" name="files" />
    <input type="file" name="files" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send it..." />
#{/}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me :/ (In case, I use Play! v1.2.4 with java 1.6.0_26). I still have a list of as many file as I have uploaded, but with the same name (the first one).

Answer (score -1):

[multi file upload with play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401364/multi-file-upload-with-play)

```
public static void overviewsubmit(File fake) {
    List<Upload> files = (List<Upload>) request.args.get("__UPLOADS");
    for(Upload file: files) {
        Logger.info("Size = %d", file.getSize());
    }
}
```

Without the File fake argument the method will not handle multipart/form-data and you'll get an empty request.args array. If anyone knows the play/standard annotation for it, let me know :)