# playframework streaming file upload "through" play not using their Blob?

Tags: playframework

I need to stream a file through playframework to cassandra hopefully using Astyanax which looks like it supports the streaming side if I give it an inputstream.  I see someone trying to do multiple files(which I may need to do later as well), but in the meantime, how do I stream a file like this in playframework 1.2.4 without using the Blob?

multiple files posting that is unanswered :(
[Multiple upload file with PlayFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880607/multiple-upload-file-with-playframework)

There is a great download example for streaming the file back
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/asynchronous#HTTPresponsestreaming

but I can't find an example for streaming upload :(.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can come to answer for Play 1.x is to take a look at the https://github.com/jimmyy/Plupload module. It claims to do chunked upload. There is no clear documentation for this, and it is not in the official repository, but it may offer a good start for you.

Failing that, Play 2.x has support for chunked uploads (if you do a search it will be one of the first responses).